# root user not loading vars in /etc/profile.d/prompt.sh

Tags: bash

I've got a simple bash script, `/etc/profile.d/prompt.sh` that loads some environment variables for use in a prompt. The vars show up fine in the a regular admin account but not for root's account. <strike>How do I get the root account to load the `/etc/profile.d/prompt.sh` script?</strike>

Why doesn't this work out of the box? Would it hurt to just source the `prompt.sh` script manually in root's .bashrc file?

I should mention I'm using debian gnu/linux.

Comment: OK, I'm getting to root with "sudo su" which I think is the problem from what I'm reading but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a dupe. Summary answer is to not do `sudo su` to switch to root. `sudo -i` works.